# Reordering cells in a PFQueryTableView?

Tags: parse-platform

How do you handle reordering of cells in a PFQueryTableView if the self.objects array is readonly?

I Can get the table to enter into editing mode and I can even rearrange the cells, but I don't know how to handle the change in the delegate method. I tried creating an `NSMutableArray` from the self.objects array but I don't know to update the objects in parse. This is what I have tried:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {

     NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:self.objects];

     PFObject *movedObject = array[fromIndexPath.row];

     [array removeObjectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
     [array insertObject:movedObject atIndex:toIndexPath.row];


     //Then trying to reassign the updated mutable array to the self.objects array is not possible because its read only. 

 }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much though I realized that the way to handle rearranging of cells with parse objects is individually  updating the rearranged objects and not by trying to create an updated array.

Comment: Can you share you you rearranged the objects so they stayed that way? Trying to do this on a subclass of PFQueryTableViewController. Thanks!